# Sceneform SDK: How to add a 3D renderable on things other than plane

Tags: android, machine-learning, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am trying to develop an app to render a 3D model of a watch on my wrist. But the Sceneform SDK detects a plane only.

I tried augmented images by augmenting the picture of my wrist, but my wrist was not detected due to too few feature points.

Any suggestion on how it can be done? I am an Android Developer and use Sceneform SDK with ARCore. I have no experience with Unity.

Please help!!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a Google [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/) model along with `ARCore` and `Sceneform`. This Machine Learning framework allows you to add to your app such features as Faces/Landmark Detection, OCR, Image Labelling, QRcode/Barcode scanning, etc.

**AI** can detect your wrist using Custom Model Inference (then ARCore can place an Anchor on it). But you have to implement a [TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/) pre-trained model.

`ML Kit` is for Android and iOS.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: a blog tutorial would be perfect... anyone .... Bueller

Answer (score 3):

While I love the idea of using ML Kit to build your own computer vision model, that's probably a tad more involved than you were hoping to make things.

Might I suggest that a quick and easy solution would be to stick a sticker on your wrist that is registered as an image target with ARCore? You could even just draw a marker on your wrist with some success.

You could then make some assumptions about the size of an average wrist for setting up some basic occlusion effect, in order to hide the bands of the watch on the other side of your wrist.

Comment: Hi AlgoRyan! But what if @Ayusch wants to make an app for customers trying on a virtual watch? Do they need to stick stickers on their wrists? I suppose if you need additional stuff for the application to work, then this app is useless for public use.

Comment: @ARGeo is correct. I want to be able to just point at my wrist and wrap a 3D model around it. Otherwise, the app would be useless to the general public, if they have to place stickers on their skin.

Comment: Totally understand, it'd be a huge pain for the user! Though maybe you could gamify it a bit somehow to reduce that pain?

Comment: You might give Vuforia's 3D object detection functionality a go? (https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Object-Recognition) It would likely still be easier than training your own ML model.